# How to listen to Route changes in react-router v4 with HashRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi i'm using ***HashRouter*** instead of ***BrowserRoute*** since I'm managing my react app on AWS s3 which is static hosting.

Now I want to integrate Google Analytics into my app and need to detect Route changes. I looked into documents which react-router team provides but couldn't get one. I know there is a way to detect changes using ***withRouter*** with ***BrowserRouter***. but I'm using ***HashRouter***.

Can anyone know how to do it with ***HashRouter***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to make a component location aware you can wrap it with the HoC ( [Higher Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) )  `withRouter` and inside the component you will have access to location, history, and match.

You can read about `withRouter` [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter).

```
const LocationAwareComponent = ({ location, history, match }) => {
    // can use location, history, or match
}
```